# Infinite differentiability of a (cumulant generating) function

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, derivatives

Suppose that I have a moment generation function $M(t)$ that is positive and finite for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. I know that this implies that $M(\cdot)$ is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Define $K(\cdot)=\log[M(\cdot)]$ to the the associated cumulant generating function. It seems "clear" that $K(\cdot)$ should also be infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ but how does one show it rigorously?

More generally, suppose that $f$ is infinitely differentiable and $g=\varphi\circ f$. What properties about $\varphi$ must be true so that we can use such properties to show that $g$ is also infinitely differentiable?